# Edit an Widget in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, widgets

I am using below code to display an Widget in Home page.

```
{{widget type="catalogsale/widget_carousel" products_count="20" template="catalog/product/widget/sale/sale_carousel_list.phtml"}}
```

But its width is too much. I am getting result like below

[image]

I have to edit this Widget. How can I do that ?

Comment: Just update it with `css`

Comment: I tried with CSS. You can check the image.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHOFH.png

Comment: Can you provide the url